# Recording android events for playback

Tags: java, android, automation

I would like to write an application that records a sequence of events in android and save them in order to do stuff like playback. For example, i can record a sequence of events when i open the settings menue and change something specific. I would like to save the event sequence and be able to play the sequence of events so that when it is play the settings menu would be opened and changed just like the events that took place in the recording.Is this possible? if so how would i go about doing this?

Comment: do you mean events inside the application or events for android OS?

Comment: @Alex events for an application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an easy way: save user actions in [preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), like: "setting", "change background"

then loop on these actions with switch case

Comment: Hi Alex, thats part of the question that i am asking how do i save user actions inside an application ?

Comment: i mean when user click setting button save in string: "setting" then when choose something save: "setting, changebackground, red" then before close application save it in preference.

Comment: Thats not what im askinf for. Im asking for -> you said when you save ... How do you save ? where do you save from ? how does that work ? thats what im asking for

Answer (score 0):

There are these projects that I know of which might
give you a head start:

**Using Python and ADB Shell**

https://github.com/tzutalin/adb-event-record

**ReplayKit for android (by Appetizer.io) - has known issues with latest androids:**
https://github.com/appetizerio/replaykit

**Android Tools (java) :**

https://github.com/senchalabs/android-tools

**Android Touch Replay (using C++) :**

https://github.com/Cartucho/android-touch-record-replay